# Index Match either Wildcard or Match across multiple columns

Tags: indexing, google-sheets, match, wildcard

I am trying to do an index match with multiple criteria and either with a wildcard or looking across multiple columns in Google Sheets.

I have a column ('Sheet1'!P:P) with each cell containing one to four numbers in the format WWWW, XXXX, YYYY, ZZZZ. I also added a formula to split the numbers into four adjacent columns WWWW | XXXX | YYYY | ZZZZ.

On a separate sheet I have two columns that represent the first and second criteria I am looking up on Sheet1. In short, I am looking up what is in 'Sheet1'!B:B based on the first and second (this is the cells with several numbers formatted as a string) criteria.

If there is only one number in column 'Sheet1'!P:P, this equation works:

```
=iferror(arrayformula(INDEX('Sheet1'!$B:$Z, MATCH(1,('Sheet1'!P:P=$A2)*('Sheet1'!G:G=C$1),0),1)),"")
```

Once there more than one number in 'Sheet1'!P:P, I tried to structure it like this and the formula breaks:

```
=iferror(arrayformula(INDEX('Sheet1'!$B:$Z, MATCH(1,('Sheet1'!P:P="*"&$A2&"*")*('Sheet1'!G:G=C$1),0),1)),"")
```

I also tried looking across the four columns where 'Sheet1'!P:P is broken out into a column per number with no luck:

```
=INDEX('Sheet1'B:B, MATCH(C$1,IF('Sheet1'!Q:T=$A3,'Sheet1'!G:G=C$1),1) )
```

I got error messaging using the wildcard and looking to match across columns. Does anyone have any idea of a work around.

Comment: Share your sheet with a sample data and sample solution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
'Sheet1'!P:P="*"&$A2&"*"
```

Try

```
REGEXMATCH(trim(Sheet1!P:P),".*"&$A2&".*")
```